# How can I kill a process using a Batch file without a minimising full screen application

Tags: command-line, batch-file

Basically, I'm using a software called Xpadder that lets me control my computer with a game pad. Problem is, when I start a game I need Xpadder to end. So I typed this batch file

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Xpadder.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Xpadder.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
TASKKILL /F /IM "Xpadder.exe"
)
```

Works a charm. Problem is though, it minimises the game when it runs! Is there anyway I can avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a shortcut to your batch-script, right-click on it and open the properties. There you'll find a drop-down where you can choose to run the script minimised.

Another way to do it would be to make the script start itself using the `min` parameter:

```
@echo off
pushd "%~dp0"
if "%1"=="done" goto runtime
for %%I in (%0) do start "" /min %%~sI done
exit

:runtime
title Minimised
echo Code goes here
pause
exit /b
```

I used `%%~sI` to run the `start` command with 8.3 names to prevent troubles with whitespace in path or file names.